# Double Integration Applied to Volume

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, volume

I am trying to solve a question from Schaum's Calculus but I have been unable to.

> Find the volume common to $\rho^2 + z^2 = a^2$ and $\rho = asin(\theta)$.

I have tried several things and the one I feel is more close to being correct was the following:

$\rho^2 + z^2 = a^2$ is a sphere of radius $a$.

$\rho = asin(\theta)$ is a cylinder.

$Volume=4I$, where $I= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{asin(\theta)} (a^2 - \rho^2)^{1/2} d\rho d\theta $.

I got the result $I=a^2 \pi^2/8$, or $V=a^2 \pi^2/2$. The answer is supposed to be $2(3\pi-4)a^2/9$.

I am probably making a mistake in the set up of the integral but I cannot spot it. Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: There is a solution for this problem in this tutorial.  Example No 43. Goodlluck http://people.math.carleton.ca/~angelo/calculus/Math2004-notes-4.pdf

Comment: @SatishRamanathan Thank you very much. I forgot the extra $\rho$ when you pass to cylindrical coordinates. So silly.